# How to avoid open litebox on small viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-plugins

I want to avoid the [litebox](https://github.com/joemottershaw/litebox/) is open on small viewports as of Android or Apple devices.

Here is what I tried, without success:

```js
$( document ).ajaxComplete( function() { 

    $('.litebox').liteBox({
        callbackBeforeOpen: function() {
            console.log('open');
            var windowsize = $(window).width();
            // test the viewport size to see if it's smaller than 480px
            if (windowsize < 1000) {
                // cancel the lightbox and load the link url
                console.log('close');
                $(this).closeLitebox();
            }
        } 
    }); 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/joemottershaw/litebox/master/assets/js/litebox.js"></script>

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOLY7bjCTTE" target="_blank" class="litebox">Video</a>
```

I get the error...

> TypeError: $(...).closeLitebox is not a function
>
> $(this).closeLitebox();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of closing it inside litebox function, try preventing it from even going into it?

You can try:

```
var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)");

if (!isMobile.matches) {
    $('.litebox').liteBox...
}
```